# Print signature with js-pdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I have a signature field in html.

```
<h3> Signature - Customer</h3>
<section class="sig">
    <section id="sig_kunden"></section>
</section>
```

The user can input his signature. This works.

I would like to be able to print this field into pdf using js-pdf.

Normally I could print this with the following code:

```
     var doc = new jsPDF ('p', 'cm', 'legal');
     doc.text (1, 1, 'Acknowledgement');
     doc.save ('/home/Test.pdf');
```

Unfortunately, I do not understand the parameters in the new jsPDF.

Any idea to get this working?

Comment: Will getting the signature uri and adding it to the pdf as an image do?

Comment: In this example all values of input parameters are evident https://parall.ax/products/jspdf/doc/symbols/jsPDF.html